# Cross Reference Table to Single Object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In postgres 12, I have a table that stores relationships between parent and child ids. I would like a query that returns a single object that has parent ids as keys, and arrays of child ids as properties.

So far, the best I have gotten is an array of objects, each with a single key that maps to an array of child ids:

Fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1854482bbfc442a24bc34b54bf5481cf

Is there some way in pg to "merge" this array of objects into a single object? (or otherwise return a single object) e.g.,

`{ 1: [3], 2: [4, 5] }`

Comment: You need to show the results that you want.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c359281b3846a73550a816ecd9e9612

Comment: @Abelisto Would you make that comment into an answer? I would love to mark it as the accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build the JSON object at the final stage:

```
SELECT
  json_object_agg(parent_id,  z.relationship) AS relationships
FROM (
  SELECT
    parent_id, array_agg(child_id) AS relationship
  FROM
    parent_child_xref
  GROUP BY
    parent_id
) z
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1c359281b3846a73550a816ecd9e9612)